# cakephp: How to set checkbox to checked?

Tags: cakephp

I am using

```
$form->input('Model.name', array('multiple'=>'checkbox');
```

I  am trying to base on model data to set certain checkboxes to checked.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 31):

cmptrgeekken's solution works for a single checkbox. I'm assuming you're generating a multiple checkboxes, for a HABTM relation or something similar.

You need to pass a array with the values of the elements that are going to be selected to the method, like this:

```
$options = array(1 => 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE');
$selected = array(1, 3);
echo $form->input('Model.name', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected));
```

is going to generate this:

```
 <div class="input select">
      <label for="ModelName">Name</label>
      <input name="data[Model][name]" value="" type="hidden">

      <div class="checkbox">
           <input name="data[Model][name][]" checked="checked" value="1" id="ModelName1" type="checkbox">
           <label for="ModelName1" class="selected">ONE</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
           <input name="data[Model][name][]" value="2" id="ModelName2" type="checkbox">
           <label for="ModelName2">TWO</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
           <input name="data[Model][name][]" checked="checked" value="3" id="ModelName3" type="checkbox">
           <label for="ModelName3" class="selected">THREE</label>
      </div>
 </div>
```

The first and third checkbox checked.

Just remember that you're actually working with a multiple select element that is just displayed as a bunch of checkboxes (Which is IMO better because of the usability).

Comment: Speaking of usability, I found that a good trick to use when creating multiple-selects is to put a wrapper-div around the options, put a border on it and have css apply overflow: auto;

Comment: Took me a while to figure out, but one can have all options checked by doing `echo $form->input('Model.name', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options, 'selected' => array_keys($options)));`

Answer (score 26):

I don't use CakePHP, but according to the docs, it appears as though you should be able to add the option `'checked'=>true`:

```
$form->input('Model.name', array('type'=>'checkbox','checked'=>true));
```

since that's one of the options of the [checkbox](http://api.cakephp.org/file/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php#method-FormHelpercheckbox) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$options = array(1 => 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE');
$selected = array(1, 3);
echo $form->input('Model.name', 
    array( 
        "name"=>$mnus['Aco']['id'],
        "type"=>"select",
        "multiple"=>"checkbox", 
        'options' => $options, 
        'selected' => $selected)
    );
```

this is the correct way for multiple check box and checked option. I am using this in cake1.3 please recheck once on your code it must work.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Form->input('Title', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>'Label', 'checked'=>'checked'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The Marko solution still working in CakePHP 2.0+

-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962499/3197383

It just need to correct with the new syntax :

```
<?php
$options = array(1 => 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE');
$selected = array(1, 3);
echo $this->Form->input('ModelName', 
    array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Its Super Simple**

```
$form->input('field_name', array('type'=>'checkbox','checked'=>true));
```

That's it.

Documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have a checkbox checked with the "label" right next to it is.

```
$form->checkbox('Model.name', array('checked'=>'checked'))?> Label
```

Label can be what ever you want though.  example: 21,000-3000, Tire, Human.  I am sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

$subjects = array(1=>'Snow boarding',2=>'Surfing',3=>'Trekking',4=>'Swimming');
$selected_skills = array(0=>2,1=>4);

// For MutiSelect box with selected 
 $form->input('skills_list',array('label' => 'Skills','options' => $subjects,'class' =>'','multiple'=>true,'selected'=> $selected_skills));

//For Multiple checkbox with checked 
$form->input('skills_list',array('label' => 'Skills','options' => $subjects,'class' =>'','multiple'=>'checkbox','selected'=> $selected_skills));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code snippet from one of my project-

```
    $categories = $this->Site->Category->find('list', array('recursive' => -1));
    $this->set(compact('categories'));

    $this->Site->Category->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('CategoriesSite')));
    $selected = $this->Site->Category->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('id'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'CategoriesSite.site_id' => $this->data['Site']['id'],
        ),
        'recursive' => 0,
    ));
    $this->set(compact('selected'));
```

Main key is for selected is `'fields' => array('id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array("fixed","varry");
$selected = "0";

echo $form->input('Model.name', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options, 'value' => $selected));
```

Use the `value` attribute to make checked default.

Answer (score 0):

```
'likes_preferences' =>array(
    'type'=>'select','label' => 'Main likes/preferences',
    'options' => $this->Ethos->toOptionsArray('preferences'),
    'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
    'div'=>array('class'=>'input select checkbox-group clearfix'),
    'hiddenField' => false,
),
```

the above code for adding the data, you need to change the field 'likes_preferences' from array to comma separated string before saving into database.

```
$preferences = implode(',',$this->request->data['Member']['likes_preferences']);
$this->request->data['Member']['likes_preferences'] = $preferences;
```

---

### EDIT MODE

```
$likes = explode(',',$this->request->data['Member']['likes_preferences']);

'likes_preferences' =>array(
    'type'=>'select','label' => 'Main likes/preferences',
    'options' => $this->Ethos->toOptionsArray('preferences'),
    'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
    'div'=>array('class'=>'input select checkbox-group clearfix'),
    'hiddenField' => false,
    'selected' => $likes
),
```

you are done, again you must convert the array to string while updating the database in edit action.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this for input with single option

```
$this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'default' => 1, 'checked' => 'checked'));
```