# how to select all the checkboxes by default in cakephp?

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to select all check boxes by default in cakephp, how can I do that

```
 $selected = $this->Form->input('user_id')                  

 <?php echo $form->input('user_id', 
                                array(
                                'multiple'=>'checkbox',
                                    'options'=>$user,
                                    'checked'=>$selected
                                )   
                            );
                ?>
```

I have followed following links but didn't get success
[cakephp: How to set checkbox to checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962463/cakephp-how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked)
[Multiple checkboxes in CakePHP - how to set which are checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168225/multiple-checkboxes-in-cakephp-how-to-set-which-are-checked)

Comment: those linked articles are stating it pretty clearly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller and iterate over all options, populating $this->request->data.
I never use the view for default values. For me this is logic and part of the controller's responsibility in case of a GET (instead of POST where it should use the posted data instead)

see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

in your case (assuming you got an array of userIds - or any other array containing them):

```
foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
    $this->request->data['Model']['user_id'][] = $userId;
}
```

remember to do this only for if (!posted).