# Checked checkbox in the view cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

I want to set my checked box to be checked if

```
$this->Acl->check($group, 'controllers/'.$selectedController.'/'.$act);
```

is returning 1. Or if the checkbox is checked before as its value is saved in acos_aros table.
I want to do that in the view but don't know how. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962463/cakephp-how-to-set-checkbox-to-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition 1

```
$condition1 = $this->Acl->check($group, 'controllers/'.$selectedController.'/'.$act) === 1;
```

Condition 2

```
$condition2 = [some other logic here];
```

Checkbox

```
<input type='checkbox' <?php if($condition1 || $condition2) echo "checked" ?>>
```